# textbox.text = iqueryable.textbox.name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

in c# winform entity framework 
im serching like this

```
var search = dataBase.tbl_Employee.First(i=>i.code == 1);
```

i have many column in database and many textBox in Form
how to fill textbox.text like this

```
foreach(textbox tb in this.control.oftype<textbox>())    
{
 tb.text = search.tb.name;
}
```

Comment: Why you need loop here? Doing it without loop will make it more simple and straight forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set name of textboxes equals to property name of model:
and like this set Text property:

```
foreach(var tb in this.Controls.OfType<Textbox>())    
{
   tb.Text=
      search.GetType().GetProperty(tb.Name).GetValue(search,null).ToString();
}
```

Comment: i dont have enough repulation to vote up there for thanks so much

Comment: @Hd.Mahmoodi, or you can set as answer.

Comment: hi Mr Reza again tanks for your nice annswer to my last question i have a question that no body can answer Me.                       'var query = from ded in Functions.searchDead
join ask in dataBase.Asker on ded.Family_Number equals ask.Family_Number
orderby ded.Last_Name'            i want to use strinng in orderby but all y try not work